# Root Mode, Sound Drivers disabled

Tags: 11.04, sound

I noticed that when logged as "root" the sound drivers are disabled, or unable to start. while under normal user they are available. How do i activate them?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, [logging in as root is a terrible idea](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#root%20account).  How are you achieving this?  Have you actually given the "root" user a password, then logged in as "root"?

Assuming this is the case (and I hope it's not), then you need to check your User Privileges.  See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26182/when-are-user-privileges-relevant) for more detail, but essentially the user will need to have "access audio devices" ticked, then log out/in.